# Solving the Heisenberg equation of motion for the spin operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time-evolution

This question is motivated by the first problem in the second chapter of Modern Quantum Mechanics (by J. J. Sakurai).

I want to find the time evolution of the spin operators ($S_x,S_y,S_z$) in the Heisenberg picture of an electron ($e<0$) subject to the following Hamiltonian:
    $$ H = -\frac{eB}{mc}S_z=\omega S_z, \quad \omega \equiv -\frac{eB}{mc}S_z$$

I want to do it by solving the Heisenberg equation of motion.

On the notation used: $A^H$ is an operator in the Heisenberg formalism and $A$ in the Schrodinger formalism.

The Heisenberg equation of motion is:

$$ \frac{dA^H}{dt} = \frac{1}{i\hbar} [A^H,U^\dagger H U]$$

For any $S_i$:
$$\frac{dA^H}{dt} = (1/i\hbar)[U^\dagger S_i U,U^\dagger H U]$$
$$ = (1/i\hbar) \omega [U^\dagger S_i U,U^\dagger S_z U] $$
$$ =(\omega/i\hbar)  (U^\dagger S_i U U^\dagger S_z U - U^\dagger S_i U U^\dagger S_z U )$$ 
usung $UU^\dagger =1$
$$ = (\omega/i\hbar) U^\dagger (S_iS_z - S_zS_i) U = (\omega/i\hbar) U^\dagger [S_i,S_z] U$$ 
$$ = \omega U^\dagger \epsilon_{i,z,j}S_j U$$

For the case $S_z$, we clearly have $d_tS_z^H = 0$. Therefore,  $ S_z^H (t) =S_z^H (0) =S_z^S $.

For the other cases, let's consider the time-evolution operator: $U=exp(-iHt/\hbar) = exp(-i\omega S_zt/\hbar)$. Then, we have:

$$ \frac{dS_i^H}{dt} = \omega \epsilon_{i,z,j} e^{-i \omega S_z t/\hbar} S_j e^{i \omega S_z t/\hbar}= \omega \epsilon_{i,z,j} S_j^H$$

which gives a system of two coupled equations:

$$ \frac{dS_x^H}{dt} = -\omega S_y^H $$
$$ \frac{dS_y^H}{dt} = \omega S_x^H $$

which leads to: 
$$ \frac{d^2S_x^H}{dt^2}   = -\omega^2 S^H_x  $$

and

$$ \frac{d^2S_y^H}{dt^2}= -\omega^2 S^H_y  $$

I am not sure how to proceed, since $S^H_{x,y}$ are operators, hence a solution of the type $S^H_{x,y} = Ae^{i\omega t}+Be^{-i\omega t}$ doesn't make sense.

Is this approach correct?

If not (most likely), where is the flaw?

If it makes sense, what is the best way to go forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each operator is represented as a 2x2 matrix:

$$S_x^H(t)=\begin{pmatrix}a(t)&b(t)\\c(t)&f(t)\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the equation

$$\frac{d^2S_x^H}{dt^2}=-\omega^2S_x^H(t)$$

becomes

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{d^2a}{dt^2}&\frac{d^2b}{dt^2}\\\frac{d^2c}{dt^2}&\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}\end{pmatrix}=-\omega^2\begin{pmatrix}a(t)&b(t)\\c(t)&f(t)\end{pmatrix}$$

Solve component-by-component, and insert initial conditions.